# How to Add Eclipse TODOs to JSPs

Tags: eclipse, jsp, todo

There is a way to add "TODO"s to Java classes so that they will show up in Eclipse's Tasks view.

```
//TODO: comment about what needs done
```

Does anyone know how to add a similar comment in a JSP so that it'll show up in the Tasks view in Eclipse? I've tried the obvious, but can't seem to make it show up.

```
<!-- TODO: this doesn't show up in the Tasks view in Eclipse -->
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Open the Preferences (Window->Preferences) and select General->Editors->Structured Text Edit->Task Tags.

From there you can mark the "Enable searching for Task Tags" setting. Please be sure JSP is active in the Filters tab.

Note: I'm using Eclipse Helios Service Release 2 (Build id: 20110301-1815). Preferences sections could change in different versions, you could always search for "task" in the preferences as Rob suggested.

Comment: I am running Kepler. I had to run "Clean and redetect tasks" on the task tags prefs page to make the jsp TODOs show up.

Answer (score 4):

Look around Eclipse preferences - you can type "task" as a filter text - you should find options there to enable task tags for JSPs.