# How to manage TODO List in javascript files through Eclipse?

Tags: javascript, eclipse

Like the title, is there any good way to use in Eclipse?

I used the function in webstorm ([here](https://www.google.co.kr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.jetbrains.com%2Fwebide%2F2012%2F10%2Fmanaging-todo%2F&ei=DGcwVZbGJ8ezmwWDn4DQAQ&usg=AFQjCNFKUn511BBQiBSqKS5XvaajIT8Xxw&sig2=ebIVnsg7AjQ3bjt5UpnTtg&bvm=bv.91071109,d.dGY&cad=rja))
But I can't find the good plugin for doing this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Add Eclipse TODOs to JSPs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157501/how-to-add-eclipse-todos-to-jsps)

Comment: I agree your comment. Even If I try this answer, but I can't display the todo tasks of javascript files(.js). How can I display this?

Comment: I'm looking at the title, and are you asking how to modify the list of words used to automatically detect tasks, or how to make them detected in the files you have?

Comment: Sorry for my ambiguous question. I tried using Eclipse TODOs. But I could see TODOs of JSP, JAVA, other types of files. But I want to see TODOs of JS files. Ok? is it clear?